# Laravel Backpack not updating JSON field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-backpack

I have a TEXT Column in my MySQL table, which I want to fill with a JSON object as string so I can define some options for the entry I am saving per row.

I only have one option yet, so I show only one checkbox, with a value of `1`. Now when the form is submitted, I validate the input via the request. To make sure that there is always a value available I check if the input exists (remember it's a checkbox) and if not, I prefill it with the option set to `0`. But when I take a look at phpMyAdmin the old value remains.

Here the example by code - I was never good in explaining my self in englisch :P

**Form**

```
    <label for="dedication" style="font-weight: normal;"><input id="dedication" type="checkbox" name="fields[dedication]" value="1" />&nbsp;Dedication</label>
```

**Request::all() overwrite**

```
public function all() {

    // get input
    $input = parent::all();

    // save empty array if fields not set
    if (!isset($input['fields'])) {
        $input['fields'] = array("dedication" => "0");
    }

    $this->replace($input);

    // dd(parent::all());

    return parent::all();
}
```

**Model**

```
protected $table = 'products';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
// public $timestamps = false;
protected $guarded = ['id'];
protected $fillable = ['product', 'description', 'price', 'campaign_id', 'quantity', 'fields'];
protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
// protected $dates = [];
protected $casts = ['fields' => 'array'];
```

**Example**

Lets say I create a Product, and don't check the `dedication` checkbox, then the Product is saved with a value of `NULL` in the `fields` column. Wanted is `{"dedication": "0"}`.

When I now update this entry, and check the `dedication` checkbox, it works. Value is `{"dedication": "1"}`.

Now, if I update the entry again, and leafe the checkbox unchecked, the `fields` column is not overwritten so the old value remains.

How can I update the values of this column?

Comment: For me, my problem was that my `$fillable` array in my model class wasn't updated after a migration had changed some of my columns. I'd remembered to add new fields to the XyzCrudController but not to the `$fillable` array.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out, that the `update` method on my crud controller doesn't pass the updated request to the `updateCrud` method of the `CrudController`. All I had to do, was to pass the updated request.

My `update` method in the `ProductCrudController` now looks like this:

```
public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
{
    // your additional operations before save here
    $redirect_location = parent::updateCrud($request);
    // your additional operations after save here
    // use $this->data['entry'] or $this->crud->entry
    return $redirect_location;
}
```